# 404 not found after webapi project install of asp.net identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I added asp.net identity to my existing web project.  now my controllers cannot be accessed.  If I launch the local brower I am able to login in successfully.  But when I go to one of the old controllers like

```
namespace PortwatchServiceV003.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST api/values
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // PUT api/values/5
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE api/values/5
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }
}
```

}

it get error 404 not found.
Do the urls get somehow changed?

webapiconfig below...

```
    public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {

        config.Services.Add(typeof(IExceptionLogger), new App_Start.AiExceptionLogger());

        //config.EnableCors();
        //var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:57007", "*", "*");
        //config.EnableCors(cors);


        // Web API configuration and services
        // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

        //use https ONLY
        //config.Filters.Add(new UseSSLAttribute());

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );



        var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your WebApiConfig?

Comment: I added the contents

Comment: Is the config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(); line new? This may be the cause. Remove the line and try again.

Comment: Where do you authenticate the request?